# Error with charset on MySQL

Tags: mysql

Trying to modify a label for a relationship I got this error

```
   #1253 - COLLATION 'utf8mb4_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
```

But the structure seems to be correct and not using utf8mb4_bin. I compared with an other instance, and with the same structure I was able to modify the label

[image]

The table itself seems to also be properly defined:
[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tables have utf8mb4 at the table level but the individual columns are utf8. This is causing a mismatch for the triggers that populate the relationship cache.

My suggestion would be to run the System.utf8conversion api call, either from api explorer or command line. Make a backup first.

Comment: Dave you're the best. I worked. Thanks!